# Como Atualizar o valor de uma variável?

Tags: python, tkinter

fiz uma função na qual tem uma variavel inicial e de acordo com que o usuário marca um checkbutton ela pega esse valor guarda na variavel e depois pega e verifica o valor dela e exclui o valor anterior coloca o atual. mas minha dúvida é, como e atualizo a variável ou seja pego o valor final dela ?
 segue o codigo

`def PegarValor(self):

```
    v = [0,0,0,0]
    if self.VnomeValor == 1:
      v.remove(v[0])
      v.insert(0, 1)
    else:
      pass

    if self.VcorValor == 1:
        v.remove(v[1])
        v.insert(1, 1)
    else:
      pass
    if self.VcpfValor == 1:
        v.remove(v[2])
        v.insert(2, 1)
    else:
        pass
    if self.VemailValor == 1:
        v.remove(v[3])
        v.insert(3, 1)
    else:
        pass`
```

Comment: é só pôr `self.v` que você conseguirá utilizar ela em toda classe, inclusive, você pode usar `v[0] = 1` para substituir o valor do primeiro elemento para 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dificil entender o seu contexto com esse fragmento de codigo, mas o que parece é que vc quer apenas fazer um "replace" na lista de acordo com os valores das variaveis VnomeValor, VcorValor, etc, não é? pelo menos olhando no codigo que voce passou, é isso que fica parecendo. A proposito, me parece que vc veio de outra linguagem, recomendo que veja a [PEP8, o guia de estilo para codificação em python](https://wiki.python.org.br/GuiaDeEstilo).

Desenvolvi uma função que recebe uma lista e um dicionario com as variaveis (no estilo pythonico) que vc postou e faz replace na lista de acordo com o valor da variavel, pelo que eu entendi, o valor da lista sera alterado para 1 se o valor da variavel for igual a 1, então ficou assim:

```
def get_list(_data, _list1):
     if _data['cor_valor']['value']==1:       
         _list1[ data['cor_valor']['pos'] ]
     if data['cpf_valor']['value']==1:
         _list1[data['cpf_valor']['pos']]=1
     if data['mail_valor']['value']==1:
         _list1[data['mail_valor']['pos']]=1
     if data['nome_valor']['value']==1:
         _list1[data['nome_valor']['pos']]=1
     return _list1   

data = {'cor_valor': {'pos': 1, 'value': 0},
        'cpf_valor': {'pos': 2, 'value': 1},
        'mail_valor': {'pos': 3, 'value': 0},
        'nome_valor': {'pos': 0, 'value': 1}
       }

list1 = [0,0,0,0]

list1 = get_list(data, list1)
print (list1)
[1, 0, 1, 0]
```

[Veja o código funcionando aqui.](https://repl.it/IHUV)

> Depois de algumas horas que postei a solução acima, retornei e vi o quão verborrágica ficou, por isso resolvi reduzi-la, veja:

```
data = {'cor_valor': {'pos': 1, 'value': 0},
        'cpf_valor': {'pos': 2, 'value': 1},
        'mail_valor': {'pos': 3, 'value': 0},
        'nome_valor': {'pos': 0, 'value': 1}
       }

list0 = [0,0,0,0]

def get_list_v2(_data, _list1):
    for d in _data:
        if _data[d]['value']==1:
            _list1[data[d]['pos']]=1
    return _list1        

list1 = get_list_v2(data, list0)
print (list1)
```

[Veja esse novo codigo aqui.](https://repl.it/IHUV/1)